# Screen orientation on tablet error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, orientation

I have a strange issue. I have an LG g700 tablet and I want to set the orientation locked. But when i test it on my nexus 5 it works well with the following code:

```
window.screen.orientation.lock("landscape")
```

But when i do the same code on my tablet it doesn't work and it gives an error like:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The page needs to be fullscreen in order to call lockOrientation(). {message: "The page needs to be fullscreen in order to call lockOrientation().", name: "SecurityError", code: 18, INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1, DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2…}code: 18message: "The page needs to be fullscreen in order to call lockOrientation()."name: "SecurityError"__proto__: DOMException
```

Is there an solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done only on full screen mode. So I suggest you add a timeout before calling `screen.orientation` just to make sure that full screen is active and ready.

```
if (document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen) {
   setTimeout(function(){
      window.screen.orientation.lock("landscape");
   }    , 200);
}
```